# sahi and symfony2

Tags: symfony, behat, sahi, mink

i would like to test behat, mink and sahi with symfony2

so, in my config_test.yml i have

```
   mink:
   base_url:  http://localhost/Symfony_Standard_2.0.15_2/symfony/web/app_test.php    
   default_session: symfony
   sahi: ~
```

and in test.feature

```
    @mink:sahi
    Scenario: Open page with products list and check it
    Given I am on "/hello"
    Then the response should contain "hello"
```

when i execute i have this

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function Buzz\Client\curl_init() in C:\wamp\
www\Symfony_Standard_2.0.15_2\Symfony\vendor\buzz\lib\Buzz\Client\AbstractCurl.p
hp on line 26

help me please,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you do not have [cURL](https://www.php.net/curl) enabled in your WAMP installation.
Actually cURL is not enabled by default in WAMP. The steps to enable it are as follows :

1. Close WAMP (if running)
2. Navigate to WAMP\bin\php(your version of php)\
3. edit php.ini
4. Search for curl, uncomment extension=php_curl.dll
5. Navigate to WAMP\bin\Apache(your version of apache)\bin\
6. edit php.ini
7. Search for curl, uncomment extension=php_curl.dll
8. Save both
9. Restart WAMP

Comment: thank's a lot, the problem is solved, but i have another, i asked another question 

here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223637/i-can-not-run-sahi-help-me-please

thank you