# I can not run sahi

Tags: symfony, behat, sahi, mink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sahi and symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222722/sahi-and-symfony2)

I would like to test behat, mink and sahi with symfony2.

In my file config_test.yml I have

```
mink:
    base_url:  http://localhost/Symfony_Standard_2.0.15_2/symfony/web/app_test.php    
    default_session: symfony
    sahi: ~
```

in my test.feature when I use

```
Scenario: Open page with products list and check it
Given I am on "/hello"
Then the response should contain "hello"
```

the result is well:

```
1 scenario (1 passed)
2 steps (2 passed)
0m5.112s
```

But when i add `@mink:sahi` I get

```
@mink:sahi
Scenario: Open page with products list and check it #             
src\Acme\DemoBundle\Features\test.feature:6
Given I am on "/hello" # Acme\DemoBundle\Features\Context\FeatureContext::visit()
Operation timed out after 5000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
Then the response should contain "hello" # 
Acme\DemoBundle\Features\Context\FeatureContext::assertResponseContains()

1 scenario (1 failed)
2 steps (1 skipped, 1 failed)
0m5.112s
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved the problem, in fact, we must run the driver sahi, before starting the test,